# Why is shared preference returning null?

Tags: java, android, object, sharedpreferences

I have been dealing with a weird error that I can't seem to figure out.

I want to make my main activity smaller, I am putting my shared preferences in its own class to be called so that it is more organized.

As of now my shared preferences is in the same class that I am trying to call it from to use and and it works fine.

But when I copy the same code create and object of it and call it I get a null object reference.

But, for some reason it works if I just chuck it in a sub class.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
public class SharedPref extends Activity {

public void write_to_key(String shared_pref, String pref_key, String value_of_key) {
    //This block of code will automatically store the key and value in the shared preferences
    //All you need to do is provide the sharedpreference, the key you wish to save the value as, and the value
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(shared_pref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(pref_key, value_of_key);
    editor.apply();
}

public String read_from_key(String shared_pref, String pref_key) {
    //This block of code will automatically read the value in the shared preferences with the provided key
    //All you need to do is provide the key you want to read and the value will be returned as a string
    SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(shared_pref, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return (shared.getString(pref_key, ""));
}

}
```

Here is my class I am trying to call it from called Navigation

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading_page_layout);
    //Get Wallet keys

    SharedPref sharePref = new SharedPref();
    walletKey = sharePref.read_from_key(MyPREFERENCES, "walletKey");
    WalletType = sharePref.read_from_key(MyPREFERENCES, "walletType");
    System.out.println(walletKey + " " + WalletType + " THESE ARE THE LOGS FOR SHARED PREFERENCES");


    //calling the broadcast receiver method to check internet in background
    this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}
```

Comment: this is a very bad implementation of shared preference

Comment: You cannot directly instantiate an `Activity` and have all its members work correctly. `SharedPref` should not extend `Activity`.

Comment: you should read more about shared preferences first

Comment: add your write_to_key code where you write shared preference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass context, instead to inherit with Activity

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

public class SharedPref {

    private Context mContext;

    public SharedPref(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void write_to_key(String shared_pref, String pref_key, String value_of_key) {
        //This block of code will automatically store the key and value in the shared preferences
        //All you need to do is provide the sharedpreference, the key you wish to save the value as, and the value
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(shared_pref, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(pref_key, value_of_key);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String read_from_key(String shared_pref, String pref_key) {
        //This block of code will automatically read the value in the shared preferences with the provided key
        //All you need to do is provide the key you want to read and the value will be returned as a string
        SharedPreferences shared = mContext.getSharedPreferences(shared_pref, MODE_PRIVATE);
        return (shared.getString(pref_key, ""));
    }

}
```

Pass context in constructor

```
SharedPref sharePref = new SharedPref(this);
String walletKey = sharePref.read_from_key("MyPREFERENCES", "walletKey");
String WalletType = sharePref.read_from_key("MyPREFERENCES", "walletType");
```

Comment: Hey Atif thanks for the response, unfortunately it is still giving me the error as shown here: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference:

Comment: Use following line SharedPref sharePref = new SharedPref(YOUR_CURRENT_ACTIVITY_NAME.this);

Comment: hmm its still not working......there is another error in my sharedprefs class The error is in my class where it says >>> SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(shared_pref, MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: what are you doing man?, you are still using your own class, read answer carefully and use my class "SharedPref"